# MNTILE SPOJ Tiling patterns

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, tiling

We have tiles of size `2 * 1`. We need to arrange the tiles to get the floor size of `m * n`.

For `m = 3`, we get arrangement like this:

[image]

My question is: In how many different ways can we arrange the tiles?

For `m = 3`, we get recurrence relation as:

```
T(n) = 4*T(n-2) - T(n-4)
```

For `m = 4`, we get

```
T(n) = T(n−1) + 5*T(n−2) + T(n−3) − T(n−4)
```

How to solve it for `n=5` and `m = n`? Is there any generalized solution?

Problem Definitions :

1) http://www.spoj.com/problems/M5TILE/
2) http://www.spoj.com/problems/MNTILE/

Answer (score 3):

Here is a link to a presentation (by some undergraduate student) about the computation of those numbers:

http://math.cmu.edu/~bwsulliv/domino-tilings.pdf

It also contains references to Kastelyn's original paper and other interesting material.

Answer (score 2):

There is a general formula for the number of valid domino tilings in an (m x n) rectangle, which was first found by Kastelyn (around 1960).

$
\prod_{j=1}^{\lceil\frac{m}{2}\rceil} \prod_{k=1}^{\lceil\frac{n}{2}\rceil} \left ( 4\cos^2 \frac{\pi j}{m + 1} + 4\cos^2 \frac{\pi k}{n + 1} \right )
$

This formula was then used to compute the topological entropy of the domino tilings (the corresponding two-dimensional subshift of finite type) - one of the few results where an explicit formula for the entropy value of a two dimensional (non-degenerate) shift of finite type is know.

Also if you already know some values for the first sizes (small n, m) a good way to find general formulas like this one is to take a look at Sloane's database of integer sequences (see https://oeis.org/ ). There you can put in the first few terms of a sequence and you will probably find the correct one in the database, together with additional terms (for larger values of n,m), a detailed description of where those sequences occur and in many cases a closed formula or a recursion to produce the terms in the corresponding sequence.